# Feature selection with continuous & categorical data (with Boruta, Decision tree etc.)

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, data-science, random-forest

I'm working on the **multi regression** with a lot of columns data which include numeric data and categorical data to decide the values of commodities.

There is a lot of data. However, to avoid overfitting problems I need to select the features which can explain the value of commodities.

First of all, I try to use **dataframe.corr** to calculate a correlation between each column with value of commodities.

To compare correlation, I use **boruta.BorutaPy**, **Random forest** technique, and **sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression** to feature selection.
Unfortunately, categorical data disturb this way. I read about these techniques work with the categorical data.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv(dir + file)

X = data.drop(['value','Id'], axis = 1)

index = X.keys()

Y = data['value']

X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size = .3)
```

This code shows how can I read a file and select the train/test data from the read data (Of course categorical data included in X dataframe).

Here is the sklearn way to select the features

```
model = linear_model.LinearRegression()

n_feat = 15    # The number of feature what I want to select

rfe = RFE(model, n_features_to_select = n_feat, step = 1)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
```

and boruta way is

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import *
from boruta import BorutaPy

rf = RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators = 100, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True)

feat_selector = BorutaPy(rf, n_estimators='auto', verbose=0, max_iter=200)

boruta_fit = feat_selector.fit(X_train.values, Y_train.values)
```

it also shows ValueError because of the value of categorical data is a string.

I want to know the solution of feature selection with categorical data **without dummy variables**.
Because I think dummy variables of each category is not appropriate to apply the multi regression.
If my opinion is wrong, I'm glad to hear your advice.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Any process you use is going to have to convert that string into a number of _some_ kind, otherwise you're trying to literally do math on letters. You could choose some kind of scale ('string_1' = 0, 'string_2' = 1...) if the values can be ordered sensibly. Even if you want to use an indicator where the values can't be ordered ('orange', 'apple', 'car crash', 'nap'), you'd need to add new columns. The n-1 columns for n values of a dummy is common and statistically sound, so I would suggest sticking with that, unless you can explain more about your objection.

Comment: My category data cannot be sorted by typical ordered.
I try to make a dummy index for categorical data, but I think it makes a bias of feature selection.
If there is "Key1" has A, B, C, and D, and 81%, 15%, 3%, 1% data included each category. When I select the feature with dummy index, A category may be selected and C, D category abandoned and ignored. However, C, D comparable category with A because of those categories included in same key values.
That's why I think a dummy index not appropriate in my case.

Comment: IIUC, `Key1` is your categorical variable, and can take values in {A,B,C,D}. Dummies would make columns `Key1_A`, `Key1_B`, `Key1_C`, and `Key1_D`, with 1/0 (for example) in the columns. Each of those is now it's own feature (and one should be excluded b/c of multicollinearity). If feature selection says `Key1_B` is important while `Key1_C` is not, there's no reason (absent knowing more about your data) to say that the resulting set of features is biased.

Comment: If I make a dummy index for all categories, how can I check the multicollinearity between columns with feature selection?
Correlation can help this problem??

Comment: See "The Dummy Variable Trap" in [this presentation](http://home.cc.umanitoba.ca/~godwinrt/3040/overheads/lecture17.pdf).